# Problem with ForEach and NavigationLink in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, list, foreach, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Here is a basic code snippet that I'm having problems with:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var pets = ["Dog", "Cat", "Rabbit"]
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(pets, id: \.self) {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text($0)) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Pets")
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report

My intention here was to get comfortable with NavigationLink, and navigate to a new page displaying just text on click of the item.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with the shorthand initializers that you are using. Either of these alternatives will work:

```swift
ForEach(pets, id: \.self) {
     NavigationLink($0, destination: Text($0))
}

ForEach(pets, id: \.self) { pet in
     NavigationLink(destination: Text(pet)) {
          Text(pet)
     }
}
```

Comment: Why does a simple $0 not work as given in the question above?

Answer (score 1):

nicksarno already answered but since you commented you didn't understand, I'll give it a shot.

$0 references the first argument in the current closure when they aren't named.

```
ForEach(pets, id: \.self) {
    // $0 here means the first argument of the ForEach closure
    NavigationLink(destination: Text($0)) {
        // $0 here means the first argument of the NavigationLink closure 
        // which doesn't exist so it doesn't work
        Text($0)
    }
}
```

The solution is to name the argument with `<name> in`

```swift
ForEach(pets, id: \.self) { pet in
    // now you can use pet instead of $0
    NavigationLink(destination: Text(pet)) {
        Text(pet)
    }
}
```

Note; The reason you get the weird error is because it finds a different NavigationLink init which does have a closure with an argument.